# which sql ce version is run on win ce 5

Tags: windows-ce, sql-server-ce

In [Datalogic Memor 944201019](http://www.frontierpc.com/point-of-sale/handheld-terminals/datalogic/memor-mobile-computer-944201019-1015356507.html)

OS is win ce 5. How could I know or check which sql ce version is suitable for win ce 5? Please share me.

Answer (score 2):

version 3.5 SP2 which you can download from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8831